# jtextpane highlight only highlight first instance

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

I am attempting to highlight multiple words in jtextpane. However, I can only highlight the first instance found.

```
String key = "are";
Highlighter h = test.outputPane.getHighlighter();
String text = test.outputPane.getText();
String arr[] = text.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String temp = arr[i];
    if (temp.equals(key)) {
        try {
            h.addHighlight(text.indexOf(temp), text.indexOf(temp) + temp.length(), DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(crawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is not enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`text.indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) only *"returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring."*. You could use [`text.indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), it will also *"start at the specified index. "*.

[image]

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;

public class Example {

    JTextPane textPane;

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("are warehouse are arearea are rare");
        hightlightAll("are");
        frame.setContentPane(textPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void hightlightAll(String word) {
        Highlighter highlighter = textPane.getHighlighter();
        String text = textPane.getText();
        String[] words = text.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
        int lastIndex = 0;
        for (String str : words) {
            lastIndex = text.indexOf(str, lastIndex);
            int endIndex = lastIndex + str.length();
            if (str.equals(word)) {
                try {
                    highlighter.addHighlight(lastIndex, endIndex, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {

                }
            }
            lastIndex = endIndex;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks. i got the portion working after referring to your explanation.

Comment: @kenAu89 I edited the code, now it should only highlight the word "are", not for example the "are" in "rare"

Answer (score 0):

`h.addHighlight(text.indexOf(temp), text.indexOf(temp) + temp.length(), DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);` will always highlight the first occurence of temp in text. And since temp is equal to your search key, it will only highlight the first occurence of your search key.

You'll need to improve your iteration code...

Comment: thanks for the response. Upon your input, i noticed that it stop looping after the first instance. thank you. I will look into it.

Comment: The problem with the solution from @LuxxMiner is that it will also highlight the 'are' in 'warehouse'.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer.